# Отключение wifi без airplane mode

Tags: linux

После последнего обновления системы `sudo rfkill block wifi` включает `airplane mode` (загорается специальная клавиша, что раздрожает). Как софтово заблокировать `wifi`, не включая его?

Comment: `nmcli radio wifi off` а если так?

Comment: @nick_gabpe у меня нет `nmcli`, это какая-то внешняя утилита

Comment: @step, это консольный Network Manager